# Responsive Navbar without Toggle button Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not new to bootstrap but neither an expert . I've seen the responsive behavior of navbar with Bootstrap using Toggle button . In fact bootstrap is great . But i'm curious that why to hide the Tabs in the navbar to make it responsive . I've gone through a few tutorials but could not find anything much useful . let's go through the scenario that what we can have in our navbar

```
1-icon
2-website title 
3-login/register buttons 
4-may be two /three images (specific to my edge)
5-dropdowns
```

Now we may allot these options the correct grid space but the thing is if we have even these **`5`** things in our navbar then a screen of **`360*640`** will move the options to down. So , the point is "can we do every thing more dynamically so that a screen of minimum **`360*640`** can handle all options . Any alternative plugin ? any other option in `bootstrap` which i may be missing ?

**Code Update**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default orange-row" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header col-xs-5 col-sm-5 ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_url %>"> <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/logo.png" /> </a>
        <a href="<%= root_url %>">
          <font  size="5" face="Comic Sans MS" color="black"><b>  waiterhelper </b></font>
        </a>
    </div>

<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7"> 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-center">
      <a href="/customers/comingsoon">
        <img src="/assets/photo-icon.png"          class="img-rounded img-icon"> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
      <a href="/customers/comingsoon">
        <img src="/assets/list-icon.png" class="img-rounded img-icon">
      </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style=" margin-right: 50px;margin-top: 6pt;">
     <select id="API_source_map"  class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info">

        <option value="google_places">Google</option>
        <option value="yelp_places">Yelp</option>

     </select> 

           </div>

<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 pull-right" style="margin-top: 6pt;margin-right:5%;">
                 <%= link_to "Logout" , registration_logout_url ,{:class => "btn btn-default unset_conversation_cookie"} %>

</div>                
  </div>  
 </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe it will help us if you post the HTML of your navbar, so it will be possible to see how it is implemented.

Comment: @Franco see the code update